# php process xml into array

Tags: php, xml

I'm tring to process xml (website) into php array.

I have tried the following code which works for everyting in results but i need to get the totalpage which i'm not able to see how I can do this.

```
function get_content($url) 
    /// basically opens the page and stores it as a variable. Buggered if I know how it works! 
    {   
        $ch = curl_init();  
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        ob_start();
        curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        $string = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $string;
        $string = NULL;
        $ch = NULL;
        $url = NULL;
    }
$url = "url";
$content = get_content($url);
$content_x = explode("<result>", $content);

foreach ($content_x as $item)
    {
        $p1 = strpos($item, '<title>');
        $p2 = strpos($item, '</title>');
        $l1 = $p2 - $p1;
        echo '<br>'.$title = substr($item, $p1, $l1);
    }
```

xml site feed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response version="2">

    <totalpage>1005</totalpage>

    <results> 
        <result>
            <title>test</title>
            <title2>test2</title2>
            <title3>test3</title3>
        <result>
                <result>
            <title>test</title>
            <title2>test2</title2>
            <title3>test3</title3>
        <result>
                <result>
            <title>test</title>
            <title2>test2</title2>
            <title3>test3</title3>
        <result>
                ........so on

    <results>

</response>
```

I need to get **totalpage** and everyting in **results**

How do get **totalpage** and is they better way to process the **results**

Comment: You should really look into using [SimpleXML](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

Comment: my webserver does not support this. so ineed to aviod this.

Comment: You server has curl but no SimpleXML? How about XML Parser or DOM extensions? If note those how about going and getting a simple XML parsing class?  If you are going to be working with XML, you don't want to do it via string manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely should not be using string manipulation to try to parse XML.  There are any number of PHP libraries that can do this.  I might recommend SimpleXML.

Usage would be:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);
$totalpage = $xml->response->totalpage;
```

Comment: i can't use this as my web server does not support this. plus i tried on my own pc. i dont get the full results when using this.

Comment: See my comment above.  You surely have some means of parsin XML available to you.  If not you should consider dumping you web host or asking them to install one of these extensions for you.  This is very basic fundamental stuff, so I would be SHOCKED, if you can;t find some extension or library you can work with.